# Is it possible to parse JSON array into a tuple with json4s?

Tags: scala, json4s

Take the following example:

```
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._
import org.json4s._

implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

case class A(name: String)
case class B(age: Int)
val json = parse("""[ {"name": "mark"}, { "age": 27 }, 5 ]""")
json.extract[Tuple3[A, B, Int]]
```

This errors out:

> org.json4s.package$MappingException: No usable value for _1 No usable
>   value for name Did not find value which can be converted into
>   java.lang.String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Json4s scalaz](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/blob/9d4d75bef2f37f15e44073760c8f9077efb7505a/tests/src/test/scala/org/json4s/scalaz/TupleExample.scala) seems to have tuple support. I am not sure if there is any built in way to do this in json4s. I generally solved this issue something like this

```
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

class MySerializer extends CustomSerializer[Tuple3[A,B,Int]](format => (
    {
        case JArray(x :: y :: z :: Nil ) => {
                ( x.extract[A], y.extract[B], z.extract[Int])}
    },
    {
        case x:Tuple3[A,B,Int] => null
    }
))
```

And then from your code do something like this

```
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats + new MySerializer
val json = parse("""[ {"name": "mark"}, { "age": 27 }, 5 ]""")
json.extract[Tuple3[A,B,Int]]
```

Comment: Yea, I ended up going the custom serializer route myself. Thanks!